# Inputs for Euler Method in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am having trouble inserting the input to a MATLAB function.

The instructor told us to use Matlab to solve the Euler method.
I can do it analytically.
The equation I am solving is
`dy/dt = t*y`
 subject to 
`y(0) = 2`.

Q1: Use Matlab to solve Equation (1) using Euler's method with time steps `dt = 0.01`, up to maximum time `Tmax = 3`.

This is my code:

```
function sol=euler1(fn,a,b,y0,n)
%Finding solution to $y'=f(x,y) using Euler's method
%Using initial condition is y(a)=y0
h=(b-a)/n;
x=a+(0:n)*h;
y(1)=y0;
for k=1:n
    y(k+1)=y(k)+h*feval(fn,x(k),y(k));
end
sol=[x',y'];
```

Comment: What's the question? What specifically does not work? Also, if `fn` is a function handle, you don't really need `feval` – just `fn(x(k),y(k))` is sufficient.

Comment: when you run the program what exactly i am going to type?

Comment: What you seem to be asking is very basic Matlab that is best learned from doing tutorials and reading the documentation. If you're just asking how to call a function, then I recommend reading [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.htm) and trying the examples.

Comment: I just want to know how do i call fn

Comment: This is not the right place to ask such basic introductory questions. A 10 minute Matlab tutorial should teach you enough to run functions.